# Removing an object from the duplicate ArrayList only

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

I've copied an ArrayList over as so:

```
MyList2 = MyList1;
```

In an attempt to load MyList2's objects with the ones which MyList1 has.

Now as I iterate through MyList2, I it.remove() some objects, but this is causing a concurrent modification exception elsewhere on the parent iteration through MyList1. I think when i it.remove() it's actually removing it from the original ArrayList as well, how do remove it only from MyList2? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem there is that you haven´t created a copy of the `ArrayList`, there are two references to the same object. If you want to copy the list, then you could do

```
Collections.copy(MyList2,MyList1);
```

or

```
MyList2 = new ArrayList(MyList1);
```

Comment: Thanks I used "MyList2 = new ArrayList(MyList1);" to properly copy it over. Everything is functional and there is no longer a concurrent exception. :)